# Trouble setting the frame for a custom camera overlay using Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller

As the question states, I'm having trouble setting the view frame for my custom camera overlay using the Swift language. I keep getting an error that states "value of optional type "CGRect" not unwrapped" that I don't quite understand. The problem line is this one:

```
cameraOverlay.frame = camera.cameraOverlayView?.frame
```

Xcode attempts to auto-correct the issue by adding a bang (!) at the end of frame, but that does not work either, and creates another error.

Here is my entire nib initialization code for my custom camera overlay:

```
@IBOutlet var cameraOverlay: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var camera = UIImagePickerController()
    camera.delegate = self
    camera.allowsEditing = false
    camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    camera.showsCameraControls = false

    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CameraOverlay", owner: self, options: nil)
    cameraOverlay.frame = camera.cameraOverlayView?.frame
    camera.cameraOverlayView = cameraOverlay
    cameraOverlay = nil

    self.presentViewController(camera, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**
Make sure your nib view does not have a white background, or else the camera will not appear. Set the view background color to clearColor, and make sure opaque is unchecked to be safe. I had this problem for a little while until I realized what was happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
    cameraOverlay.frame = camera.cameraOverlayView!.frame
```

Actually you are using `?` optional chaining which returns frame as wrapped in `optional`.`!` is used for optional unwrapping

or you can also do

```
    //it will not crash but you should handle nil case using unwrap by `!` as shown above using `if` condition
    cameraOverlay.frame  = (camera.cameraOverlayView?.frame)!
```

Comment: Perfect! So frustrating, yet such a simple fix, haha. Thanks so much! Really appreciate it

Comment: Be aware that this will cause a crash of `cameraOverlayView` is `nil`.

Comment: I found that the first answer you gave seemed to work the best while also nested in an if condition to check for nil like you suggested....... My nib view loads with all of the buttons on it, but the camera does not open. I only get a white background. Do you have any idea what might be going on there?

Comment: Never mind, just figured it out! My nib view had an opaque white background. I guess I assumed that the camera view would open up over it, but that was not the case.